# a model using the TensorFlow framework to detect dashed circles

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have a question about TensorFlow. I trained a model using the TensorFlow framework to detect dashed circles. However, my training and validation datasets only consist of 219 and 146 images respectively. The training accuracy and validation accuracy have been consistently 1, and the training performance has been poor. What could be the reason for this?

```
import os 
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore")
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam 
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator 

base_dir='./data/Flug'
train_dir=os.path.join(base_dir,'train')
validation_dir=os.path.join(base_dir,'validation')


train_Kreis_dir=os.path.join(train_dir,'Kreis')



validation_Kreis_dir=os.path.join(validation_dir,'Kreis')



model=tf.keras.models.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(32,(3,3),activation='relu',
                           input_shape=(224,224,3),
                           kernel_regularizer=tf.keras.regularizers.l2(l=0.01)),
    tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(2,2),
    
    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(64,(3,3),activation='relu',
                           kernel_regularizer=tf.keras.regularizers.l2(l=0.01)),
    tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(2,2),

    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(128,(3,3),activation='relu',
                           kernel_regularizer=tf.keras.regularizers.l2(l=0.01)),
    tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(2,2),

    
    tf.keras.layers.Flatten(),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(512, activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')

])

print(model.summary())


model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',optimizer=Adam(lr=1e-4),metrics=['acc'])

train_datagen=ImageDataGenerator(
    rescale=1./255,
    rotation_range=40,
    width_shift_range=0.2,
    height_shift_range=0.2,
    shear_range=0.2,
    zoom_range=0.2,
    horizontal_flip=True,
    fill_mode='nearest')
test_datagen=ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)

train_generator=train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    train_dir,
    target_size=(224,224),
    batch_size=2,
    class_mode='binary'
)

validation_generator=test_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    validation_dir,
    target_size=(224,224),
    batch_size=2,
    class_mode='binary'
)

history=model.fit_generator(
    train_generator,
    steps_per_epoch=108,
    epochs=20,
    validation_data=validation_generator,
    validation_steps=73,
    verbose=2
)

model.save('model1.h5')
```

Comment: Hi @HYP, How does the dataset look like? Could you share the dataset if it can be shared to check and understand the issue. What will be the meaning of 'Poor training performance' when accuracy is 1 for both train and val dataset. Please share the model.fit() output as well.